# Create new columns in DataFrame based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame is like this:

| case_id | start_month | close_month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | 2023-02 | 2023-03 |
| A02 | 2023-02 | 2023-05 |
| A03 | 2023-03 | 2023-04 |
| A04 | 2023-03 | 2023-05 |
| A05 | 2023-04 | 2023-05 |

I want to create the dummy columns "open_xxxxxx", for example, "open_202302", "open_202303", etc. with the values being either 1 or 0 depending on "start_month" and "close_month".

The case is open until the month before the "close_month". That means if "start_month" is "2023-03" and "close_month" is "2023-05", "open_202303", "open_202304" will be 1.

The desired result:

| case_id | start_month | close_month | open_202302 | open_202303 | open_202304 | open_202305 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | 2023-02 | 2023-03 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A02 | 2023-02 | 2023-05 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| A03 | 2023-03 | 2023-04 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| A04 | 2023-03 | 2023-05 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| A05 | 2023-05 | 2023-05 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I have thought of for loop but couldn't yield any results.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df['start_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_month'])
df['close_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['close_month'])

tmp = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['start_month'], x['close_month'], freq='MS', inclusive='left'), axis=1).explode()
tmp = pd.crosstab(tmp.index, tmp)
tmp.columns = tmp.columns.strftime("open_%Y%m")
df = pd.concat([df, tmp], axis=1)

df.iloc[df['start_month'] == df['close_month'], 3:] = 0
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  case_id start_month close_month  open_202302  open_202303  open_202304  open_202305
0     A01  2023-02-01  2023-03-01            1            0            0            0
1     A02  2023-02-01  2023-05-01            1            1            1            0
2     A03  2023-03-01  2023-04-01            0            1            0            0
3     A04  2023-03-01  2023-05-01            0            1            1            0
4     A05  2023-05-01  2023-05-01            0            0            0            0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) here to benefit from efficient broadcasting operations:

```
# ensure datetime
df['start_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_month'])
df['close_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['close_month'])

# generate dates between min and max
cols = pd.date_range(*df[['start_month', 'close_month']].stack().agg(['min', 'max']), freq='MS')
a = cols.to_numpy()

# perform numpy broadcasting, convert to DataFrame and join
out = df.join(
 
 pd.DataFrame(((df['start_month'].to_numpy()[:, None] <= a)
             & (df['close_month'].to_numpy()[:, None] > a)
              ),
            index=df.index, columns=cols.strftime('%Y%m'))
    .astype(int)
    .add_prefix('open_')
    )
```

Output:

```
  case_id start_month close_month  open_202302  open_202303  open_202304  open_202305
0     A01  2023-02-01  2023-03-01            1            0            0            0
1     A02  2023-02-01  2023-05-01            1            1            1            0
2     A03  2023-03-01  2023-04-01            0            1            0            0
3     A04  2023-03-01  2023-05-01            0            1            1            0
4     A05  2023-04-01  2023-05-01            0            0            1            0
```